# How to make Electron + Angular

Tags: angular, electron, single-page-application, desktop-application

How to make a SPA application using both? Simple and direct.

Joining the two applications seems possible but it is very complicated.

I need a tutorial to do it in a simple way.

Answer (score 1):

example funcional

https://github.com/luizcarlospedrosogomes/pontua/tree/master/pontua-cliente-react

clone project 
run: npm install
run: npm run dev

Answer (score 0):

If your SPA is nodejs family only(e.g no php/dotnet/java backend), like angular

add entry  "main":"main.js" to package.json

add [main.js](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/) from electron quick start

And you are run it if electron installed

here is [simple electron project](https://github.com/Longfld/Angular4Electron)

here is its original  [angular project](https://github.com/Longfld/AngularQuickStartForBeginning)

Of cause if we go more details, we need special treatment for different issue.